# How to get objects owned by a user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I Have the following url:

```
url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", views.index, name="index"),
```

And the following models:

```
class PUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Playlist(models.Model):
    puser = models.ForeignKey(PUser)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In my index view, how do I filter the Playlists to find those owned by the user passed in the url? (Also does the OneToOneField() also ensure that each Playlist is linked to django-auth user?)

Comment: You mean like using `.fliter()`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do I filter by the username captured in the url? Does the OneToOneField and ForeignKey enable me to filter like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in your get_queryset, you can try :

```
filter(puser__user__username = username_from_url)
```